# Apache Active MQ connect exception using Java program from remote machine

Tags: apache, exception, connection, jms, activemq-classic

I was trying to run Apache Activemq , broker ran successfully at localhost. At same machine JMS producer , consumer Java applications ran successfully . BUT I changed Uri to tcp://192.168.1.1:61616 in activemq.xml and ran the broker in machine 1( 192.168.1.1) . I ran consumer in machine 1.  I ran producer from machine 2 in LAN. But producer  caused jms exception. ConnectException. Connection refused. As a result producer and consumer can not communicate in LAN . Please guide.

Comment: need to provide more context, code snippets and error logs, don't make people guess what you did.

Comment: APache ActiveMQ was running in local host as per /conf/activemq.xml default configuration.   I ran Producer and Consumer java program in localhost... its a success.          But when Producer and Consumer Java program is run in different machine ( of course ActiveMQ running as localhost) ConnectException occurs....Can not Communicate.     Consumer & ACtiveMQ is running in Machine1   and Producer ruuning in Machine2 with Broker URL tcp://<machine2 IP Addr>:61616   Kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you have this setup:

- Machine1: ActiveMQ Broker and Consumer
- Machine2: Producer

Then you need to setup your configurations like this:

1. ActiveMQ Broker: in activemq.xml set to tcp://192.168.1.1:61616
2. Consumer: tcp://192.168.1.1:61616
3. Producer: **tcp://192.168.1.1:61616**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. It was firewall that was preventing connection. I disabled firewall, things is running fine. Regards.